# Can I divide a MIPI Clock between two MIPI CSI Cameras?

Tags: sensor, camera

So, I'm facing this problem I have encountered while building a pcb.
I need to mount two MIPI CSI cameras (2 data lanes each) onto a chip that has 4 MIPI data lanes. The thing is, the chip only has 1 MIPI-Clock and each camera need its own Clock, how could I feed both cameras with just the chip's clock.

The chip is a Tibbo's Plus1.

Comment: Why do you think you need to divide the clock? Why not simply feed it to both cameras? Have you asked the manufacturer? That should be your first port of call.

Comment: I tried asking the manufacturer, but they didn't exactly give me a satisfying answer, I'm really a newbie at that, when I said "divide" I meant feed it to both cameras now that I see. Still I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is the cable spacing and connectors for all signals and power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new to both of us and you have a lot more reading to do than I will. [But this is where I started.](https://www.google.com/search?q=MIPI%20D-PHY%20interface%20Specification,%20v1.1&sxsrf=AOaemvK-8cWMvL75xjUUJbpxRECGNTvzBw:1638328159569&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv0ef_z8H0AhUGVs0KHc7VB7UQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1704&bih=821&dpr=1)

[image] [ref](https://mixel.com/ip-cores/multi-standard-serdes/lvds-d-phy-combo-transmitter/)
[image] [ref](https://mixel.com/ip-cores/mipi-cores/c-d-phy-combo/)
**MIPI D-PHY** components are current-mode binary Bi-phase differential, not much different than ethernet, HDMI and USB but not the same. It can use LVDS technology for your 800 MHz clock, but they seem to be using SMB RF connectors with thin 50 Ohm coax cables (braid or semi-rigid copper) for each 100 ohm, differential channel, rather than CAT4e or CAT5 approach, which might work, but D-PHY experts would say it is not compliant.

**side-comment:** *I believe it is because of the evolution to the newer [more advanced MIPI C-PHY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCavk7ahGZU) that uses 3 coax wires per HS Gbps lane for the highest speed data in a **three-phase modulation of 3 levels** for future 22 Megapixel video imaging, that is new and different than the other protocols. This allows the receiver can operate a lower bandwidth for higher bit-rate data with simpler Rx designs and lower latency than ethernet RLL protocols..*   [image]

There are several sources of current mode-clock drivers [TI's clock splitters or equiv.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65dphy440ss.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1638328083324&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn65dphy440ss), They also gang the current mode drivers to increase voltage levels and margin for the faster than 800 MHz rates. This is for the "eye" data pattern windows from impedance imperfections and stray noise from adjacent lanes CPU clocks, SMPS power switching harmonics, AC grid, and other gnd noises.  A tiny SMT Common-Mode choke is a good part to have to raise the differential impedance and lessen the stray current noise that can be coupled.  See low-voltage differential signals ([LVDS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Low-voltage_differential_signaling)). [See page 3-10](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slld009/slld009.pdf)  These can be controlled-impedance paths 100 to 120 ohms differential.

The detailed MIPI specs are limited to the members of the group of OEMs only but the recommended physical interfaces must exist to be purchased,  yet [Tibbo "a la cart" modules](https://tibbo.com/store/tps/tibbits.html) are rather pricey didn't show any to me.

I suspect the clock drivers may need the option to be ganged to boost the current for best signal integrity. So plan on at least 4 outputs combined to 2 ports.

Look for existing IoT package designs and signals, as the chips will be a supply issue and a major design learning curve for you, to enable the best integrity on your 1st go. These interfaces can go much faster, but these cams are limited in resolution

Four PinMuxable capture modules

MIPI-CSI camera interface for up to two cameras supporting resolutions up to 1328x864 @ 60 fps
MIPI video interface supporting resolutions up to 1366x768 and 1312x816
HDMI 1.4 video interface for connecting monitors with up to 720p resolution

[The specs for the  MIPI-CSI camera port are:](https://tibbo.com/store/plus1/specifications.html)
Supports up to two cameras    Compliant with;
MIPI CSI-2 Specification, rev. 1.01
[MIPI D-PHY](https://forum.digikey.com/t/mipi-interfaces-its-physical-layers-characteristics/3177) interface Specification, v1.1
Supported modes  High-speed (HS) mode  1.0 Gbps per lane  ( and LS low speed mode 10MHz )

REF Doc: https://mixel.com/publications/
https://mixel.com/mipi-d-phy-rx-an-optimized-test-configuration/

[And this is where I stopped (Xilinx)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCEcz6JiaBk)